# How to import a class from a buildscript dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, apache-commons

I want to access the StringUtils methods within my Gradle Script. Therefore I defined its MavenRepo in the buildscript closure. After I added the import statement I thought I was able to use this class. But an error tells me otherwise. What do I miss?

**gradle.build**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.xetra11.test.Main"

task execute(){
     File file = new File("/log/file.txt")
     StringUtils.touch("/log/file.txt")
}

buildscript {
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    }
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies{
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
}
```

**Error output**

```
~/Workspace/Development/Java/gradle_test/ gradle buildDependents
gradle buildDependents

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/xetra11/Workspace/Development/Java/gradle_test/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/home/xetra11/Workspace/Development/Java/gradle_test/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/home/xetra11/Workspace/Development/Java/gradle_test/build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
   @ line 1, column 1.
     import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`, from its package suggests, is in commons-lang 2.x.  Package names for `commons-lang3` was changed to `org.apache.commons.lang3`.

So, either use `org.apache.commons:commons-lang:2.6` as dependency, or change your import to `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`